# Formatting Wordpress article content in iOS app

Tags: ios, wordpress, uiwebview, uitextview

I'm working on a Wordpress blog/article reader app for iOS which will draw from an existing Wordpress site. As of right now the app's design is as simple as a UITableView of articles which drills down to a particular article. I don't think I'll have a problem fetching the content (I found some nice info from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702317/wordpress-blog-iphone-app-reader)) but my question has to do with formatting the returned content, specifically for the article itself.

The way I see it, I can either have the content come back as HTML from the WP blog's mobile website, or I can get only the article's unformatted text. Here lies my dilemma:

If I request for the formatted HTML to be returned, I get all sorts of other web-specific stuff with it (links, images, navigation bars, etc.). Just throwing that HTML in a `UIWebView` would be screen-scraping and make for an awful user experience. However, I would get some text formatting.

If I request for the raw article text and put it in a `UITextView`, I don't have a dynamic way to format that text (as far as I know). However, I would be rid of all those excess web elements.

Is there a 'best of both worlds' where I can have neatly formatted text minus the elements I don't want to appear in the app? Please give suggestions, point out anything I'm not aware of, and steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Consider installing the [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/) plugin (from the makers of Wordpress), which includes a JSON API for full integration. Of course, there's also the Wordpress app.

Comment: @MarcusAdams - Does Jetpack provide ways to specify how the returned content is formatted?