# Recreating blog post structure in a native iOS view

Tags: ios, wordpress

I am currently working on the reader app for one of Wordpress blogs. With the help of those two posts I've gone quite far:

[How Can I Incorporate my WordPress Blogs into an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584117/how-can-i-incorporate-my-wordpress-blogs-into-an-ios-app)
[Wordpress Blog iPhone App Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702317/wordpress-blog-iphone-app-reader?rq=1)

But now I am struggling with a question if it is actually would be possible to show the post in native view instead of just loading an html code inside UIWebView? I can get everything I need to recreate the post: text, headers, images, video urls, but the question is how to recreate the structure of the post? So how can I know how textual information and images are located relatively to each other inside the post?

I am using https://github.com/topfunky/hpple to parse HTML files inside the app.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think one way of doing this is that you create a JSON feed for your blog and use this feed to build native UI using UItableView etc.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/feed-json/
```

Comment: Hi Zee, thanks for your respond. I am already using this JSON plugin to display a feed in a collection view. Each cell is a post preview, with title, thumbnail and a short description. Then when you are tapping on on of the cells it opens a corresponding blog post. So, my problem is that I can not figure out how to display this post in other way then  UIWebView.

Comment: If you are able to fetch the text out that html, you can display it on a ViewController (a totally customised view). Otherwise you will have to use UIWebViews (which isn't a bad idea as well).

Comment: Exactly, I can fetch text and all image urls, and of course can display them in UIView, but the problem is that I can not recreate the structure of the post. So lets say if post looks like: HEADER - IMAGE - SUBHEADER - IMAGE - TEXT - ANOTHER IAMGE - TEXT , I can fetch all this elements, but how can I put them in UIView accordingly?

Comment: If the layout of the post is not consistent, you should use webview or may be mixed approach.

Comment: Yeah,UIWebView seems to be only one solution now. But what I would like to accomplish is a sort of algorithm which scans the html code and makes guide-marks, like ok - here is a header, and then there is an article text, there is an image and so on. Do not where to start though, stuck in research phase.